# React Hooks: conditionally render a component but with access to the whole state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Let's say my state is represented by an object like that:

```
state = {
    array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

I know if i use:

```
const state = useSelector(state => state.array)
```

My component re-render every time one of the elements of the array changes, but i don't want it. So, a solution can be:

```
state = {
    render: false,
    array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

And now i can:

```
const state = useSelector(state => state.render)
```

And handle the rendering by conditionally dispatching some actions. But in this way i have no access to the array anymore.
The problem here is that in my project the are components who need to re-render every time the array updates, and components who need to re-render only in specific cases. Another solution is to create another store only for the component which need to re-render rarely, but it seems too wired to me.

Answer (score 3):

`useSelector` accepts [a second argument `equlityFn`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector):

```
const result: any = useSelector(selector: Function, equalityFn?: Function)
```

If `equlityFn` returns `true`, no subscription update will accurate, so the render won't result from the selector.

```
const state = useSelector(
  (state) => state.array,
  (prevState, currState) => {
    return isRender(currState);
  }
);
```